# Updating multiple subdocument arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have a collection full of products each of which has a subdocument array of up to 100 variants (SKUs) of that product:

e.g.

```
{
    '_id': 12345678,
    'handle': 'my-product-handle',
    'updated': false
    'variants': [
         {
              '_id': 123412341234,
              'sku': 'abc123',
              'inventory': 1
         },
         {
              '_id': 123412341235,
              'sku': 'abc124',
              'inventory': 2
         },
         ...
    ]
 }
```

My goal is to be able to update the inventory quantity of *all* instances of a SKU number. It is important to note that in the system I'm working with, SKUs are **not** unique. Therefore, if a SKU shows up multiple times in a single product or across multiple products, they all need to be updated to the new inventory quantity.

Furthermore, I need the "updated" field to be changed to "true" *only if the inventory quantity for that SKU has changed"

As an example, if I want to update all instances of SKU "abc123" to have 25 inventory, the example of above would return this:

```
{
    '_id': 12345678,
    'handle': 'my-product-handle',
    'updated': true
    'variants': [
         {
              '_id': 123412341234,
              'sku': 'abc123',
              'inventory': 25
         },
         {
              '_id': 123412341235,
              'sku': 'abc124',
              'inventory': 2
         },
         ...
    ]
 }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: the old question has multiple answers indicating this cannot be done, however last year this limitation was removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB 3.6 has introduced the *filtered positional operator* `$[<identifier>]` which can be used to update multiple elements of an array which match an array filter condition. You can read more about this operator here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

For example, to update all elements of the `variants` array where `sku` is `"abc123"` across every document in the collection:

```
db.collection.update({}, { $set: { "variants.$[el].inventory": 25 }}, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ "el.sku": "abc123"}] })
```

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way in a single query to update a document's field based on whether another field in the document was updated. This is something you would have to implement with some client-side logic and a second query.

EDIT (thanks to Asya's comment):

You can do this in a single query by only matching documents which will be modified. So if nMatched and nModified are necessarily equal, you can just set updated to true. For example, I think this would solve the problem in a single query:

```
db.collection.update({ variants: { $elemMatch: { inventory: { $ne: 25 }, sku: "abc123" } } }, { $set: { "variants.$[el].inventory": 25, updated: true }}, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ "el.sku": "abc123"}] })
```

First you match documents where the `variants` array contains documents where the `sku` is `"abc123"` and the `inventory` does not equal the number you are setting it to. Then you go ahead and set the inventory on all matching subdocuments and set `updated` to true.

Comment: It's too bad it can't be done in a single operation but this is great information. I used your solution to update what I needed and then based on the "nModified" value that gets returned, I run another query that updates "updated". Thanks!

Comment: actually it *can* be done in a single update - you just have to be careful/clever in your update query predicate instead of using empty predicate.  It will also make it faster.

Comment: If you craft your query to only match documents which need to be updated then you can $set updated to true on those documents.

Comment: Ah of course! I think I see what you're saying. I just updated the answer to show an example of what I think you're describing. Would you mind taking a look to see if it's what you had in mind?